# Print a section in the end of each page VB .Net crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

**I want to print a section in the end of each page
is that possible **strong text****

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly what you need, why not simply use the Page Footer section?

Comment: no i have 2 section the first i want to show it in the all page except the last page and the second section i want to show it in the last page and in the other no

Answer (score 0):

Use case is still not very clear, but the Report Footer section is the one you should use to display information only at the end of the report.